# shell replace command using regular expression command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora

I have a file having value as

```
        [1] => 3192592
        [2] => 4365943
        [3] => 4679044
        [4] => 5413434
        [5] => 5686682
        [6] => 6104529
        [7] => 6373851
        [8] => 7247848
        [9] => 7281395
        [10] => 7349817
```

I need a command of shell script to replace all [] codes like [1] [2] [3].

i.e out would be 3192592,4365943,4679044,5413434 and so on

Comment: Please clarify what you wish by giving the output you're looking for

Comment: Also, [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: It is not clear to me. You want to replace what? With what? Do you want to remove `[]` from the files, so it become `1 => 4365943`? Do you want to replace `[1]` with another number `[123]`?

Answer (score 0):

simple use

```
:1,$s/.* => \(.*\)/\1/g
```

Answer (score 0):

if your "test" file looks like:

```
[1] => 3192592
[2] => 4365943
[3] => 4679044
[4] => 5413434
[5] => 5686682
```

than you can achieve the output:

```
3192592,4365943,4679044,5413434,5686682
```

executing the command:

```
 cat test | cut -d " " -f 3 | sed 's/$/,/' | tr -d '\n' | sed '$s/.$//'
```

`cut -d " " -f 3` - cuts the third column

`sed 's/$/,/'` - puts comma at the end of each line

`tr -d '\n'` - removes the new line character

`sed '$s/.$//'` - removes the comma after the last entry